# textbox below table column

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add a text-box inside a 6 columned table?

It would look something like this

```html
<table id="table" class="table">

  <thead id="search-result">

    <tr>
      <th>table 1</th>
      <th>table 2</th>
      <th>table 3</th>
      <th>table 4</th>
      <th>table 5</th>
      <th>table 6</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>

  <tbody id="result">

    <tr>
      <td>content 1</td>
      <td>content 2</td>
      <td>content 3</td>
      <td>content 4</td>
      <td>content 5</td>
      <td>content 6</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

under the content  tags there would be a 100% textbox. is that possible?

Comment: Could you add a new row with `colspan="6"` and the textbox inside?

Comment: yup! thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered. thanks to Mr. Alvaro Montoro.

I've just added a new row with `colspan="6"` and the textbox inside it.